# How to make full text search case Insensitive

Tags: views, 8, search

I'm using [Search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) (8.x-1.0-beta3) and [Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db) (8.x-1.0-beta3). I have created DBIndex Server and created index for content type 'Test' and then created search index view with filter 'Full text search'. But I observed search is case sensitive. How to make this search as case insensitive.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the below steps:

1. Click on Configuration > Search and metadata > Search API
2. Click on Index and go to Processors format . Enable the checkbox Ignore case Makes searches case-insensitive.
   [image]
3. Clear the index and reindex the items

Comment: My pleasure. welcome

Comment: Don't forget to enable your custom field under "Processor settings -> Ignore Case" section.